# Task. How to find out the amount that will remain on the user's wallet after js purchases

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

There are three arrays, the data comes from the back-end and we do not know exactly which names or products will come, we need to calculate how much the user has spent and how much he has left in his wallet. It should be borne in mind that when the user does not have enough money, he can use a loan, this money will go to his wallet additionally.

I tried to solve through a huge number of loops, going through each array and comparing the values, but I need a solution with the algorithmic complexity On.

```
    var product = [
    {'name':'пряник', 'price':10},
    {'name':'кофе', 'price':2},
    {'name':'мороженное', 'price':4},
    {'name':'макароны', 'price':5},
    {'name':'персик', 'price':6},
    {'name':'ананас', 'price':15},
]
var purse = [
    {'name':'Катя', 'cash':100},
    {'name':'Даня', 'cash':200},
    {'name':'Ваня', 'cash':400},
    {'name':'Саня', 'cash':500},
    {'name':'Маня', 'cash':600},
    {'name':'Кира', 'cash':150},
]

var purchases = [
    {'name':'Катя', 'item':'пряник'},
    {'name':'Даня', 'item':'макароны'},
    {'name':'Даня', 'item':'кофе'},
    {'name':'Даня', 'item':'кофе'},
    {'name':'Маня', 'item':'ананас'},
    {'name':'Катя', 'item':'мороженное','credit': 20},
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this would help? I briefly considered merging the objects into one big set of objects that had all the information, which would make it easier to format. However, I decided instead to re-lookup the information on each loop. This should be a good start, I hope it helps!

```js
var product = [
    {'name':'пряник', 'price':10},
    {'name':'кофе', 'price':2},
    {'name':'мороженное', 'price':4},
    {'name':'макароны', 'price':5},
    {'name':'персик', 'price':6},
    {'name':'ананас', 'price':15},
];
var purse = [
    {'name':'Катя', 'cash':100},
    {'name':'Даня', 'cash':200},
    {'name':'Ваня', 'cash':400},
    {'name':'Саня', 'cash':500},
    {'name':'Маня', 'cash':600},
    {'name':'Кира', 'cash':150},
];
var purchases = [
    {'name':'Катя', 'item':'пряник'},
    {'name':'Даня', 'item':'макароны'},
    {'name':'Даня', 'item':'кофе'},
    {'name':'Даня', 'item':'кофе'},
    {'name':'Маня', 'item':'ананас'},
    {'name':'Катя', 'item':'мороженное','credit': 20},
];

function displayInfo(name, walletVal) {
  const displayArea = document.querySelector("#display");
  const spendSummary = document.createElement("div");
  spendSummary.classList.add("spendSummary");
  const nameEle = document.createElement("div");
  nameEle.classList.add("name");
  nameEle.innerText = name;
  spendSummary.appendChild(nameEle);
  const walletEle = document.createElement("div");
  walletEle.classList.add("wallet");
  walletEle.innerText = walletVal;
  spendSummary.appendChild(walletEle);
  displayArea.appendChild(spendSummary);
}

const names = [...new Set(purchases.map(e => e.name))];
for (const name of names) {
  const filteredPurchases = purchases.filter(e => e.name == name);
  const costs = filteredPurchases.map(
    ({item: itemName}) =>
    product.find(item => item.name == itemName).price
  );
  const creditsArr = filteredPurchases.filter(e => e.credit)
    .map(e => e.credit);
  const totalCredit = creditsArr.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
  const totalCost = costs.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
  const cash = purse.find(e => e.name == name).cash;
  const currentWallet = cash + totalCredit - totalCost;
  displayInfo(name, currentWallet);
}
```

```css
#display {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  
  font-family: arial;
}

.spendSummary {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.name {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="display">
</div>
```